# Por que o polimorfismo não funciona com Genéricos?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, genéricos, collection, polimorfismo

Ao tentar compilar o seguinte código obtive um erro.

```
import java.util.*;
class Animal { }
class Cachorro extends Animal { }
public class TestePoli {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Animal> cachorros = new ArrayList<Cachorro>();
    }
}
```

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to List

O seguinte exemplo também faz uso de polimorfismo entretanto sem o uso de Genéricos, e funciona perfeitamente:

```
class Animal { }
class Cachorro extends Animal { }
public class TestePoli {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal cachorro = new Cachorro();      //polimorfismo
        Animal[] cachorros = new Cachorro[10]; //polimorfismo com Arrays
    }
}
```

Inclusive nesse exemplo se usa o polimorfismo com Arrays, que seria algo similar ao List, e roda sem problemas.

Por que não é possível fazer uso do polimorfismo com Genéricos?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**É possível fazer uso de polimorfismo com Genéricos, mas não da mesma forma como é feito com Arrays**

O motivo pelo qual você não pode criar um objeto `ArrayList<Cachorro>` em uma referência `List<Animal>` é por que seria impossível para a JVM evitar que fosse adicionado um `ArrayList<Gato>` em um objeto `ArrayList<Cachorro>`. Veja o exemplo:

```
//suponhamos que fosse possível fazer o que a linha abaixo sugere
List<Animal> cachorros = new ArrayList<Cachorro>(); //apenas suponha, essa linha não compila!
```

Nada impediria de você fazer isso nas linhas subsequentes:

```
cachorros.add(new Cachorro()); //OK
cachorros.add(new Gato()));    //ops! adicionou um Gato em uma lista de Cachorros
```

Pois a variavel de referencia é uma `List<Animal>`, logo a JVM não é capaz de impedir de adicionar qualquer subtipo de animal à essa lista.

Qual o problema de adicionar um objeto do tipo `Gato` na coleção? Nenhum, até o momento que se deseje ler a coleção e tratar seus elementos como `Cachorro`s.

```
for(Cachorro c: cachorros) { //gera um ClassCastException se ler um objeto de Gato
}
```

Genéricos servem para deixar o código mais seguro e fácil de ler, logo o trecho acima nunca gerará um [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) desde que a lista seja devidamente iniciada com o uso de Genéricos, assim:

```
List<Cachorro> cachorros = new ArrayList<Cachorro>();
```

O código acima garante que nada diferente de `Cachorro`, ou seus subtipos, serão adicionados à coleção.

**Como usar polimorfismo e Genéricos então?**

O problema está apenas em adicionar elementos que não são do tipo esperado à coleção, logo, **o uso do polimorfismo com Genéricos pode ser usado se**:

**1) Não for adicionado nada à coleção**

Você pode passar um objeto que é um subtipo para uma variável de referência de uma coleção, desde que você não adicione nada à ela.

Exemplo:

```
import java.util.*;
class Animal { 
    private String nome;
    Animal(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }
    public String getNome() { return nome; }
}
class Cachorro extends Animal { 
    Cachorro(String nome) { super(nome); }
}
class Gato extends Animal { 
    Gato(String nome) { super(nome); }
}
public class Teste{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Gato> gatos = new ArrayList<Gato>();
        List<Cachorro> cachorros = new ArrayList<Cachorro>();
        gatos.add(new Gato("Gray"));
        gatos.add(new Gato("Brown"));
        cachorros.add(new Cachorro("Pim"));
        mostrarNome(gatos);     //chama o método polimorficamente
        mostrarNome(cachorros); //chama o método polimorficamente
    }
    //método polimórfico para mostrar nome
}
```

Seria algo extremamente incoveniente fazer um método `mostrarNome()` para cada subtipo de `Animal`, correto? Além de que, toda vez que surgisse um `Animal` novo um novo método deveria ser criado, algo que vai totalmente contra os princípios da orientação a objetos.

Mas existe uma solução:

```
    //método polimórfico para mostrar nome
    public static void mostrarNome(List<? extends Animal> animais){
        for(Animal a: animais) {
            System.out.println("Me chamo: " + a.getNome());
        }
    }
```

O trecho `<? extends Animal>` no parâmetro do método `mostrarNome()` indica que é possível passar listas de subtipo de `Animal` para a variável de referência `animais` e garante que nada será adicionado à essa lista.

Se tentar colocar o seguinte código dentro do método `mostrarNome()`:

```
animais.add(new Cachorro("Tobi"));
```

O compilador retornará o seguinte erro:

> The method add(capture#2-of ? extends Animal) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Cachorro)

**2) For adicionado algo a coleção de modo seguro**

Eventualmente você pode se encontrar em uma situação que seja necessário adicionar objetos à coleção.

Exemplo:

```
public class Teste{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //chama o método polimorficamente
        List<Animal> animais = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        adicionarAnimais(animais); //chama o método polimorficamente
    }
    //método polimórfico que adiciona animais
}
```

Você pode adicionar, desde que você garanta para o compilador que a coleção seja supertipo do objeto que se deseja adicionar.

```
    //método polimórfico que adiciona animais
    public static void adicionarAnimais(List<? super Animal> animais) {
        animais.add(new Cachorro());
        animais.add(new Gato());
        animais.add(new Papagaio());
    }
```

O trecho `<? super Animal>` diz que o parâmetro aceita qualquer argumento que seja uma lista de `Animal` ou qualquer supertipo dele. Ao invés de passar uma lista de `Animal` poderíamos ter passado uma lista de `Object` que também funcionaria:

```
List<Object> objetos = new ArrayList<Object>();
adicionarAnimais(objetos);
```

Logo, desde que se passe uma lista de `Animal` ou de qualquer supertipo de `Animal` o método `adicionarAnimais()` funciona bem.

**Por que com Arrays não existe tais restrições?**

A diferença dos Arrays é que eles possuem uma exceção em tempo de execução: [ArrayStoreException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html).

Os Genéricos não existem em tempo de execução, toda programação que utiliza Genéricos é de uso exclusivo do compilador. Logo, não existe proteção em tempo de execução para Genéricos, e de fato, NÃO é necessário! Já que toda a proteção foi feita em tempo de compilação. (Estamos falando de Java 5 em diante, já que antes do Java 5 não existiam Genéricos).

Em outras palavras, em tempo de execução, o JVM sabe qual é o tipo dos Arrays, mas não sabe o tipo de uma coleção.

Para ilustar:

```
class Animal { }
class Cachorro extends Animal { }
class Gato extends Animal { }
public class TesteArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal[] cachorros = new Cachorro[10];
        cachorros[0] = new Cachorro();
        cachorros[1] = new Gato();
    }
}
```

Compila, mas gera uma exceção em tempo de execução.

Answer (score 3):

Existe um erro de interpretação na sua pergunta quando você diz "Por que o polimorfismo não funciona com Genéricos ?" pois o código List cachorros = new ArrayList(); é polimórfico em relação as coleções List / ArraList. Na verdade poderia ser qualquer Tipo na cadeia de herança de java.util.Collection que compilaria.

**O problema a meu ver é outro:**

A linha abaixo compila

```
Animal[] cachorros = new Cachorro[10]; //polimorfismo com Arrays
```

Mas não é segura pois

```
cachorros[0] = new Gato("miau");
```

também compila mas está semanticamente errada. Ocorrerá erro em tempo de execução do tipo ClassCastException

A abordagem com Tipos genéricos é mais segura, mas o programador é responsável por criar um mecanismo que garanta que não ocorra manipulação incorreta de tipo, que neste exemplo abaixo é garantida pelo método `add` da classe `ListaCachorro`. Na vida real usaremos uma Interface mas simplifiquei o exemplo por motivos didáticos.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Animal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListaCachorro cachorros = new ListaCachorro();
        cachorros.add(new Cachorro("Rex", "au au"));
    }
}

class Cachorro extends Animal {
    public Cachorro(String nome, String latido) {
    }
}

class Gato extends Animal {
    public Gato(String nome, String miado) {
    }
}

class ListaCachorro extends ArrayList<Animal> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Animal a) {
        // seu codigo de verificação de tipo que lança RuntimeException
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: A pergunta está equivocada pois é possível usar polimorfismo com genéricos, mas tenho que discordar do seu ponto de vista pois você apontou um caso de polimorfismo com `Collection` e não com `Genéricos`. No caso a pergunta deveria ter sido: `Por que o polimorfismo não funciona com **Collection**?`. Você mesmo disse: `List cachorros = new ArrayList(); é polimórfico em relação as **coleções** List / ArraList`.

Comment: Já seu método `public boolean add(Animal a)` me parece ser uma boa alternativa para usar polimorfismo com Collection && Genéricos.