# Diferenças entre <T> e <?>

Tags: java, genéricos

Qual a **diferença** entre as notações `<T>` e `<?>` em Java? Qual a **motivação** no uso destes recursos e onde cada um é **fundamental**?

Comment: `<T>` quando temos um tipo de dado determinado para o Generics, `<?>`  quando não sabe o tipo de dado(`(List<?> elements)`) essa lista vai aceitar qualquer tipo de  dado no caso.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

O `T` em `<T>` é um *placeholder* do tipo que ele vai representar para uma determinada variável dentro de uma classe. Ele é usado na declaração de classes e de seus métodos. Exemplo:

```
class MeuGenerico<T> {  //T abreviacao de tipo
    private T var;
    public MeuGenerico() { }
    public MeuGenerico(T var) { this.var = var; }
    public T getVar() { return var; }
    public void setVar(T var) { this.var = var; }
}

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MeuGenerico<Integer> mg = new MeuGenerico<>(42);
        System.out.println(mg.getVar());
    }
}
```

Saída:

> 42

Ele é usado quando se quer criar uma classe onde suas variáveis são de um tipo que não é definido no momento em que ela é escrita, mas sim no momento que ela é usada, deixando a critério do usuário dessa classe qual será o tipo da variável no lugar do `T`.

Além de `T` que é uma abreviação para o "tipo", existem outras siglas padronizadas por convenção entre os desenvolvedores Java:

> E - Elemento
>   K - Chave
>   N - Número
>   T - Tipo
>   V - Valor

Exemplo: [`Interface Map<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Entretanto, essas siglas **não são** caracteres especiais reservados pelo compilador, você pode usar outros caracteres que preferir, como `f`, `J`, `Z`, ou até mesmo palavras inteiras, como por exemplo `meuTipo` ou `_$$_`. A regra que rege sobre o que pode ir dentro do `<>` é a mesma que define como podem ser os nomes das variáveis, portanto, sua palavra não pode começar com números e de forma alguma pode ser um `?`, assim como também não pode ser um `@` nem mesmo um `#`, dentre vários outros caracteres especiais que igualmente não são permitidos.

Apesar de ter essa liberdade para escrever o que quiser para ser o *placeholder*, sempre tente seguir a convenção, pois isso facilita a comunicação entre os desenvolvedores.

Mais detalhes em: [Wiki de tag de 'genéricos'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/gen%C3%A9ricos/info) e também nesse [tutorial da Oracle sobre Genéricos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

---

Já o `?`, no contexto de genéricos, basicamente serve como um *wildcard*, pois ele representa "qualquer tipo". Sua função é permitir o uso do polimorfismo junto com genéricos.

Quando seguido pelo palavra reservada `super`, por exemplo `<? super Number>` ele aceita que qualquer objeto cujo supertipo é Number seja lido ou escrito a uma variável, pois é seguro tratar como Number qualquer subtipo dele. Por exemplo:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class MeuGenerico<T> {  //T abreviacao de tipo
    private T var;
    public MeuGenerico() { }
    public T getVar() { return var; }
    public void setVar(T var) { this.var = var; }
}

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MeuGenerico<? super Number> mg = new MeuGenerico<>();
        //escrevendo em uma variável
        mg.setVar(new Integer(1));                      //válido
        mg.setVar(new Float(2.0f));                     //válido
        mg.setVar(new BigInteger("99999999999999"));    //válido
        //mg.setVar(new String("999999999"));           //inválido!!
    }
}
```

Vale lembrar a hierárquia:

> - java.lang.Object
>
>   - java.lang.Number
>
>     - java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
>     - java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
>     - java.math.BigDecimal
>     - java.math.BigInteger
>     - java.lang.Byte
>     - java.lang.Double
>     - java.lang.Float
>     - java.lang.Integer
>     - java.lang.Long
>     - java.lang.Short

Portanto, somente os objetos das classes Number e seus subtipos podem ser associados à variável da nossa classe genérica.

Quando seguido da palavra reservada `extends`, por exemplo `<? extends Number>`, novamente ele somente aceitará objetos que sejam subtipo de Number, entretanto dessa vez não permitirá escrever às variáveis. Exemplo:

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MeuGenerico<? extends Number> mg = new MeuGenerico<>();
        //tentando escrever em uma variável
        //mg.setVar(new Integer(1));                    //inválido!!
        //mg.setVar(new Float(2.0f));                   //inválido!!
        //mg.setVar(new BigInteger("99999999999999"));  //inválido!!
        //mg.setVar(new String("999999999"));           //inválido!!
    }
}
```

Nesse momento pode ser que você esteja se perguntando "Como ler algo dessa variável se não é possível escrever nada nela?".

É <strike>simples</strike> assim: Como sua utilização é permitir a leitura do conteúdo das variáveis mas sem permitir escrever nelas, essa declaração é utilizada quando se deseja um parâmetro de um método para que lhe seja passado como argumento uma variável com dados já escritos nela. Basicamente é para permitir a utilização de métodos polimórficos ao mesmo que se utiliza genéricos. Exemplo:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class MeuGenerico<T> {  //T abreviacao de tipo
    private T var;
    public MeuGenerico() { }
    public T getVar() { return var; }
    public void setVar(T var) { this.var = var; }
}

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MeuGenerico<Number> mg = new MeuGenerico<>();
        mg.setVar(new Float(9.0f));                 
        fazAlgoImportante(mg);      //passa o argumento
        mg.setVar(new BigInteger("999"));                   
        fazAlgoImportante(mg);      //passa o argumento
    }
    public static void fazAlgoImportante(MeuGenerico<? extends Number> mg) {
        //nesse momento mg tem permissão apenas de leitura
        System.out.println(mg.getVar().intValue() * mg.getVar().intValue()); //OK
        //mg.setVar(new Float(9.0f));   //inválido!!
    }
}
```

O argumento recebido pelo método `fazAlgoImportante()` será tratado como se fosse um objeto da classe MeuGenerico, sendo o tipo usado no lugar de `T` como se fosse um Number. Nesse momento, o tipo que ocupará o lugar de `T` pode ser qualquer subclasse de Number, mas independente de ele ser um Integer, AtomicLong ou BigInteger, somente os métodos disponibilizados pela [classe Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) poderão ser acessados, como é o comportamento esperado de acordo pelo que se é conhecido do polimorfismo.

Mais detalhes sobre o uso de polimorfismo e genéricos [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8679/3117).

Já `<?>` seria idêntico a fazer `<? extends Object>`.

Vale a pena lembrar que `<? extends Object>` não é a mesma coisa que `<Object>`, pois no primeiro caso você não pode escrever na variável.

## Conclusão

Como podemos ver, o *placeholder* e o *wildcard* possuem características bem distintas e sob hipótese nenhuma podem ser intercambiados. Portanto, respondendo a sua pergunta de qual é a diferença entre os dois é: TODA! Já que de comum apenas o fato de eles serem usados com genéricos, de resto não há mais nada.

Comment: Não conhecia esse recurso contido em <? extends Object> de impor restrição à escrita do objeto. Parabéns! Muito boa a resposta.

Comment: @GeisonSantos a função dele é permitir métodos polimórficos com genéricos, essencial para a linguagem mas ao mesmo tempo um pouco confuso, se tentar escrever na variável terá problemas. Que bom que gostou da resposta, apesar de eu não ter respondido diretamente seus negritos acredito que tenho ficado entendido no decorrer do texto.

Comment: Math, foram respondidos sim, embora não de maneira direta, o que não era de maneira alguma uma exigência minha. Você explicou até mais do que foi pedido :)

Comment: É uma pena eu não ter descoberto essa resposta há 2 anos atrás, quando me ferrei em uma prova sobre este tema :/. De qualquer forma, excelente resposta.