# Por que usar um retorno genérico?

Tags: java, java-8, genéricos, métodos-estáticos

Estava olhando a assinatura dos métodos da classe [**`Optional`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) e não entendi o que significa esse `<T>` na frente do retorno do método [**`empty()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty):

```
public static <T> Optional<T> empty()
```

Ele retorna um `Optional<T>`, certo!?
Mas por que usar um `<T>` na frente do retorno do método?

Comment: Relacionado: [Diferenças entre <T> e <?>](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68554/3117)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Entendendo a sintaxe

Considerando a parte importante:

```
<T> Optional<T> empty()
```

`T` é uma *variável de tipo*. Isso funciona mais ou menos como uma variável em um *template*, onde você pode substituir `T` por um tipo qualquer, lembrando que *tipo* em Java é sinônimo de classe (não confundir com *tipos primitivos).

O primeiro `<T>` diz: este método vai usar um tipo genérico `T` em algum lugar. É como uma dica para o compilador (e para o programador desatento).

O tipo de retorno do método `Optional<T>` então diz que o tipo genérico de `Optional` deve ser do mesmo tipo genérico do método.

Confuso, né? Quando o Java vai saber o tipo T? Isso ocorre no momento em que você vai usar o método. Como o @Maniero já disse, quando você chama o método atribuindo o resultado a um certo tipo, o Java consegue inferir o tipo usado naquela chamada.

Por exemplo, se você está atribuindo o retorno do método a uma variável do tipo `Optional<String>`, então `T = String` e você pode ler o método como:

```
Optional<String> empty()
```

De fato, as IDEs mais avançadas como Eclipse e IntelliJ irão mostrar a assinatura com a substituição adequada de `T` durante o autocompletar sempre que for possível inferir tipo pelo contexto atual.

É bom lembrar que a inferência de tipos genéricos é uma garantia em tempo de compilação de que não haverá incompatibilidade entre tipos durante atribuições e acessos. Portanto, isso nada influencia durante a execução do programa.

## Outro exemplo

Esta não é a única maneira do compilador subentender o tipo genérico. Um exemplo clássico é um método que retorna um mesmo tipo passado por parâmetro:

```
static <T> T instanciar(Class<T> classe) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    return classe.newInstance();
}
```

Da mesma forma que no primeiro exemplo, `<T>` diz que o método é genérico, o retorno será do tipo `T` e o método recebe uma classe do tipo `Class<T>`. Exemplo de uso:

```
Cliente c = instanciar(Cliente.class);
Produto p = instanciar(Produto.class);
```

Como o Java infere o tipo `T` aqui? O compilador olha o tipo de classe passado no parâmetro e assim garante que o valor retornado seja do mesmo tipo.

Diferente do caso da pergunta, onde o tipo é inferido pela variável que recebe o retorno do método, aqui o tipo é inferido por um dos parâmetros informados.

Por exemplo, `Cliente.class` é um atributo que retorna um objeto do tipo `Class<Cliente>`, portanto o retorno da primeira chamada será to tipo `Cliente`, onde `T = Cliente`.

## Porque `<T>` é necessário antes do tipo do método

Há classes/interfaces genéricas e métodos genéricos. Se a classe/interface for genérico, os métodos dela podem usar o tipo genérico.

Exemplo:

```
interface Generico<T> {
    T empty();
}
```

Ou:

```
class Generico<T> {
    T empty() { ... }
}
```

Entretanto, se apenas o método é genérico, a declaração precisa vir antes do método. Isso vale para métodos estáticos e de instância.

Note que você pode misturar classes e métodos genéricos e usar diferentes nomes para as variáveis de tipos:

```
class Generico<T> {
    T empty() { ... }
    static <X> Optional<X> empty() { ... }
    <Y> Optional<Y> of(Y instance) { ... }
}
```

Entretanto, considere que [existe uma convenção para nomes de variáveis de tipos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Creio que a decisão de exigir a declaração do tipo genérico foi tomada por questões de legibilidade do código, além de evitar sintaxes obscuras para não confundir um tipo genérico `T` com um `class T {}`.

## O tipo genérico é estritamente necessário?

Não. Os genéricos em Java são apenas uma questão de segurança para o programador.

Você bem pode fazer isso:

```
public static Optional empty() {
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

E voltamos à era do Java 1.4, onde não havia genéricos, mas em compensação *casts* e erros de `ClassCastException` apareciam em todo lugar.

Comment: "Entretanto, se apenas o método é genérico, a declaração precisa vir antes do método, como no exemplo.", apenas métodos estáticos ou instâncias de classes também?

Comment: @Patrick Se a variável genérica não pertence à classe ela deve ser declarada em todos os casos.

Answer (score 12):

Este é um *placeholder* para o tipo que será usado. É como se fosse uma super variável. O "valor" dela é o tipo que foi escolhido do uso do método ou classe. Até aí provavelmente você sabe.

A questão é que um método estático não tem como saber que tipo foi selecionado para a classe. Afinal o método pertence à classe e não à instância e a classe não é instanciada. Então o método precisa ser chamado indicando qual é o tipo que deve ser usado nele. Este primeiro `<T>` é a sintaxe usada para receber este tipo.

Portanto você pode usar:

```
Optional<Integer> x = Optional.empty();
```

neste caso ele vai chamar o equivalente a:

```
public static <Integer> Optional<Integer> empty() ...
```

Alternativa de chamada dentro de uma expressão:

```
Optional.<Integer>empty();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/GenericReturn.java).

Se o método tivesse um parâmetro igual ao retorno ele poderia inferir por ele mas neste caso o único jeito é ser explícito.

Se me perguntar se dava para ter uma sintaxe sem isto eu acho que sim mas os criadores da linguagem quiseram diferenciar explicitamente o caso, ou sabem de algum problema que eu não sei.

Lembre-se sempre que os métodos da classe são completamente distintos dos métodos da instância e portanto o tipo de uma pode ser diferente do tipo da outra

Comment: Eu não entendi o  `<T>` antes. Ele poderia ser omitido? O retorno é um `Optional<T>`, se a assinatura fosse `public static Optional<T> empty()` seria a mesma coisa?

Comment: Não seria. O Java não aceita esta sintaxe.

Comment: Ainda que esse fosse um método de instância, uma construção dessa poderia ser útil caso ele operasse em outros tipos arbitrários que não um dos tipos genéricos da classe. A propósito, muito interessante essa forma de usar, não conhecia, +1.