# Quando e por que devo utilizar classes templates Class <T> em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, genéricos

Eu quando vejo que uma classe ela recebe isso, eu acho assustador.

Comment: Isso é `Generics`. Há aplicações interessantes, mas realmente nunca parei pra pensar em que casos é recomendado.

Comment: Uhum class Generics...

Comment: Isso. Não são templates. Template é uma coisa relacionada que existe em C++ (mas bem diferente)

Comment: Até alguém responder... [Usando Generics em java](http://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-generics-em-java/28981)

Comment: Ops achava que era a mesma coisa.

Comment: Acho que pode dar uma luz: [Diferenças entre <T> e <?>](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68554/3117)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Em C++ isto pode se chamar *template*, mas em Java estas classes são chamadas de genéricas.

Isso é necessário quando uma classe pode usar a mesma estrutura básica e os mesmo algoritmos com diversos tipos de dados. Pense em algo que pode ser feito igualzinho com `Boolean`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, etc. Tudo é igualzinho, só muda o tipo do dado que será usado para armazenar na classe. Como você resolve isto? Faz uma classe para cada tipo desses, copiando elas e só mudando o tipo?

Quando tiver que dar manutenção vai lembrar de fazer em todas igualzinho? Não tem condições, certo?

Aí você pode usar o tal do *generics*. Com isto pode **variar** o tipo do dado básico que será usado na classe de acordo com a forma que ela for instanciada. Então esse `T` aí é uma espécie de "super-variável", que será substituído por um tipo específico quando a classe for instanciada.

```
class Exemplo<T> {
    private T x;
    Exemplo(T x) => this.x = x;
    public T getValue() => x;
}
```

Depois usa:

```
Exemplo<String> teste1 = new Exemplo<String>("teste");
teste1.getValue();
Exemplo<Boolean> teste2 = new Exemplo<Boolean>(true);
teste2.getValue();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Generics.java).

Tudo funciona. No primeiro exemplo, todos os lugares que tinha o `T`, vai virar `String`. E no segundo onde tinha `T` vira `Boolean`, ficaria algo assim:

```
class Exemplo<String> {
    private String x;
    Exemplo(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Assim uma única classe resolve o problema para todos os tipos sem ter que ficar copiando código, que vai causar problemas de manutenção.

O Java está repleto dessas classes. As coleções de dados costumam se beneficiar muito disto. No começo Java não tinha esse recurso, então você tinha um `ArrayList` "pelado" assim mesmo. Então ele aceitava qualquer coisa. Até funciona, mas imagine que você pode misturar números, com `String`s, com `Cliente`s (uma classe que você definiu), com qualquer outra coisa. Quando se criou o tal do `ArrayList<T>`, você cria uma variável que guarda `ArrayList<Cliente>` e esta lista só pode guardar `Cliente`s. Fica mais seguro. Basicamente esta é uma coleção que pode ser usado com qualquer tipo já existente no Java ou criado pelos programadores.

Simplificadamente é isso. Tem maneiras de usar de forma mais avançada, fazer restrições de que tipos podem ser usados em `T`, ter outros *slots* para generalizar outras partes com um tipo diferente, enfim... vai perguntando conforme for usando e for surgindo novas dúvidas.

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) (continue acompanhando as páginas do tutorial).

Comment: `ArrayList` é um exemplo disso correto?

Comment: Sim, claro, vou melhorar.

Comment: Muito boa resposta! Eu sempre procurei uma boa forma de explicar isso.

Comment: Entendi! Agora sim faz sentido para mim e do jeito que você explica fica tudo muito fácil, bigown.

Answer (score 0):

Os Generics também são muito úteis em métodos nesse exemplo :

```
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... objects) {
       return ...
    }
```

você receberá uma lista do tipo T baseado em seus parâmetros;