# Como fazer o TypeScript aceitar o valor "useRef" no React?

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

```
export const Test = (): JSX.Element => {
    const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleClickOutside(event: MouseEvent) {
            if (wrapperRef.current && !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
                console.log("Fora!");
            } else {
                console.log("Dentro!");
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, [wrapperRef]);

    return (
        <div ref={wrapperRef}>
    )
};
```

Em "!wrapperRef.current." o TypeScript me mostra este erro:

> (property) `MutableRefObject<null>.current: null`
>
> "Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolvo isto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Elementos do DOM

Quando uma referência é criada para um elemento do DOM, ela pode:

1. Referenciar o elemento do DOM;
2. Ser `null` - porque, por exemplo, o componente foi desmontado, então não tem o que referenciar.

No código da pergunta, a checagem de `null` já está sendo feita, o que é bom. Qual o problema, então?

Não tem como o `useRef` saber o tipo de referência que armazenará se ele é inicializado como `useRef()` ou `useRef(null)`. Para resolver isso, basta indicar o tipo esperado:

```
useRef<Tipo | null>(null); // inicializar com `null` é opcional, mas prefiro deixar explícito
```

No caso da pergunta, o `Tipo` é `HTMLDivElement`.

## Valores não-nulos

Se um valor for armazenado ao invés de uma referência à um elemento do DOM, `useRef` pode nunca ter uma referência nula, por exemplo:

```
type Tipo = { nome: string };
useRef<Tipo>({ nome: 'Stack Overflow' });
```

Nesse caso, mesmo quando o componente estiver sendo desmontado, a referência não será nula.

---

Esse "jeito" que o `useRef` aceita um tipo se chama *Generics*. Segue algumas referências sobre:

- [Documentação do TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)
- [Quando e por que devo utilizar classes templates Class <T> em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111749/100416) (é sobre Java mas o conceito é o mesmo)
- [O que é programação genérica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/100416)