# Diferença de extends e super - Generics Java 7

Tags: java, genéricos

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença de super e extends ao declarar algo generico no java, vamos para o código que fica mais facil.

```
class Pai { } 
class Filho extends Pai {   }
class Filha extends Pai {   }

public void main( String agss[] ) {

    //Qual a diferença entre < ? super Pai > e <Pai>
    List<? super Pai> a = new LinkedList<>();
    a.add( new Pai() );
    a.add( new Filho() );

    List<Pai> b = new LinkedList<>();
    b.add( new Pai() );
    b.add( new Filho() ); 


    //O que pode ser populado nesta lista?
    List<? extends Pai> c = new LinkedList<>();
    c.add( new Pai() ); //??
    c.add( new Filho() ); //? filho extends de pai 


    List<? extends Pai> d = new LinkedList<Filho>();//Pq isso compila se eu não posso popular a lista com filhos ?
    d.add( new Filho() ); 
}
```

- Qual a diferença entre `< ? super Pai >` e `<Pai>` ?
- O que pode ser inserido em uma `List<? extends Pai>` ?

  - Por que isso compila se eu não posso adicionar um `Filho` a lista ? `List<? extends Pai> d = new LinkedList<Filho>()`

Comment: Talvez esse tópico responda a sua pergunta: [Por que o polimorfismo não funciona com Genéricos?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8679/3117)

Comment: Não tinha visto essa outra pergunta, talvez seja mais direcionada

Comment: A resposta da duplicata parece responder perfeitamente isso.

Comment: Lendo a reposta duplicada, não consegui compreender o uso do extends.

Comment: @DavidSchrammel Leia a primeira parte, sobre covariância.

Comment: @DavidSchrammel Eu votei para fechar a pergunta porque, embora a outra pergunta não seja igual, as respostas lá respondem perfeitamente ao que foi perguntado aqui. Pelo menos é meu entendimento que se fosse para responder esta eu poderia simplesmente copiar e colar. Se você quiser saber alguma coisa a mais sobre o assunto, pode editar a pergunta ou criar outra. Lembre que perguntas podem ser reabertas quando apropriado.

Comment: @utluiz consegui compreender as questões abordadas em http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs