# ArrayList não aceita Polimorfismo de Sobrecarga?

Tags: java, polimorfismo, sobrecarga

Estou tentando fazer uma sobrecarga do método somar, mas aparentemente isso não funciona com ArrayLists. Confirmam?

```
Métodos:

    public int somar(ArrayList <Classe> classe){...}
    
    public int somar(ArrayList<Filme> filmes){...}
    
    public int somar(ArrayList<Aula> aula){...}
```

Comment: Não achei [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) mais recente mas os genéricos foram introduzidos na linguagem Java para fornecer verificações de tipo mais rígidas em **tempo de compilação**. Para implementar genéricos, o compilador Java aplica a eliminação de tipo substituindo todos os parâmetros em tipos genéricos por Object portanto o bytecode produzido contém apenas classes, interfaces e métodos comuns e conseqüentemente, os genéricos não geram sobrecarga em **tempo de execução**.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode fazer overload com tipos genéricos, a informação do tipo é removida em tempo de execução (veja sobre type [erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)), por isso o erro.

Você pode usar arrays tipados em vez de `ArrayList` genérico, ou deixar a assinatura do método genérico.

Por exemplo: caso suas classes estendam `TipoComum`, a assinatura ficaria:

```
public int somar(ArrayList<? extends TipoComum> lista){...}
```

Nesse caso você teria um único método em vez de um para cada subtipo de `TipoComum`.

Veja também a resposta de [#8679](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8679/por-que-o-polimorfismo-n%C3%A3o-funciona-com-gen%C3%A9ricos)